# How to convert multiple columns of list of dictionary, set, tuple to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I have some structure and data

```
CusID   Name    Shop    Item                                                Card                          Type               Price
1       Paul    Pascal  [{"Food":"001","Water":"Melon","Dessert":"Mango"}]  [{"Main":"Yes", "Second":""}]   {"VIP":"YES"}   24000
2       Mark    Casio   [{"Food":"001","Water":"Apple","Dessert":"Mango"}]  [{"Main":"", "Second":"Yes"}]   {"VIP":"YES"}   30800
3       Bill    Nike    [{"Food":"004","Water":"","Dessert":""}]            []                              {}               900
```

I want to split Item, Card, and Type columns. This is the expected output

```
Name    Shop    Food    Water   Dessert Card_Main   Card_Second VIP Price
Paul    Pascal  1       Melon   Mango   Yes                     YES 24000
Mark    Casio   1       Apple   Mango               Yes         YES 30800
Bill    Nike    4                                                   900
```

Code for the dataframe:

```
d = [{'CusID': 1, 'Name': 'Paul', 'Shop': 'Pascal', 
  'Item': [{"Food":"001","Water":"Melon","Dessert":"Mango"}],
  'Card': [{"Main":"Yes", "Second":""}], 'Type': {"VIP":"YES"}, 'Price': 24000}, 
  {'CusID': 2, 'Name': 'Mark', 'Shop': 'Casio', 'Item': [{"Food":"001","Water":"Apple","Dessert":"Mango"}], 
   'Card': [{"Main":"", "Second":"Yes"}], 'Type': {"VIP":"YES"}, 'Price': 30800}, 
 {'CusID': 3, 'Name': 'Bill', 'Shop': 'Nike', 'Item': [{"Food":"004","Water":"","Dessert":""}],
  'Card': [], 'Type': {}, 'Price': 900}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Here is my code for dataframe.
There are '  ' in dictionary of list but dataframe look like no difference!

```
d = [{'CusID': 1, 'Name': 'Paul', 'Shop': 'Pascal', 
  'Item': '[{"Food":"001","Water":"Melon","Dessert":"Mango"}]',
  'Card': '[{"Main":"Yes", "Second":""}]', 'Type': '{"VIP":"YES"}', 'Price': 24000}, 
  {'CusID': 2, 'Name': 'Mark', 'Shop': 'Casio', 'Item': '[{"Food":"001","Water":"Apple","Dessert":"Mango"}]', 
   'Card': '[{"Main":"", "Second":"Yes"}]', 'Type': '{"VIP":"YES"}', 'Price': 30800}, 
 {'CusID': 3, 'Name': 'Bill', 'Shop': 'Nike', 'Item': '[{"Food":"004","Water":"","Dessert":""}]',
  'Card': [], 'Type': {}, 'Price': 900}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: for columns having lists and dictionaries it is usually better to paste `df.to_dict()` as it it hard to reproduce the data

Answer (score 2):

Not that dynamic but this can be solved using:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Item').str[0].dropna().tolist())
b = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Card').str[0].dropna().tolist()).add_prefix('Card_')
c = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Type').tolist())
out = df.join(i for i in [a,b,c]).fillna('')
print(out)
```

---

```
   CusID  Name    Shop  Price Food  Water Dessert Card_Main Card_Second  VIP
0      1  Paul  Pascal  24000  001  Melon   Mango       Yes              YES
1      2  Mark   Casio  30800  001  Apple   Mango                   Yes  YES
2      3  Bill    Nike    900  004
```

Comment: It can't work in my code because there are difference dataframe structure. I have ' ' such as 'Item': '[{"Food":"001","Water":"Melon","Dessert":"Mango"}]'.   In your code, 'Item': [{"Food":"001","Water":"Melon","Dessert":"Mango"}]

Comment: The result of  df["Item"].str[0]   is  [,  then it isn't work